# ¿Qué sintaxis puedo usar para hacer resto que no sea mod?

Tags: c#

Soy principiante en esto, mi profesor no me deja usar el mod para hacer resto, quiero saber que otra funcion matematica puedo hacer el resto.
(Estoy usando visual studio 2019, lenguaje de programacion C#)

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: enlace del recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y también te recomiendo dar una lectura al contenido de este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: fuck you!!!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay otra función en C# para hacer el resto salvo el operador % (resto = 5 % 3; // el resultado será 2), lo que te pide tu profesor es que la implementes.